# How to execute further batch file commands after running "ftp" commands contains in the batch file itself

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I have a .bat document where I do some operations with FTP. I want to end the FTP connection and get to finish with the terminal on the desired directory.

I'm trying this, but when it gets to `quit`, it stops.

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\Foilder\project\angular
call ng build

@FTP -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open connection
user
password

cd httpdocs/project

mdelete *.woff

quit

cd %USERPROFILE%\Foilder\Subfolder
```

It gives me this message right after doing the `quit` and never runs the next line.

```
221 Goodbye.
```

Ideal scenario, run this last `cd` command and have the terminal ready on the folder that I want to run it. Thing is that I have to do some uploads to two different FTP servers and it would be great to have the console finishing in the folder where I run "dev.bat" to get it to work

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script uses a known *hack* that allows you to specify `ftp` commands directly in the batch file.

The `%~f0` is replaced with the path to the batch file itself. So the `ftp -s:%~f0` runs `ftp` and tells it to use the batch file itself as `ftp` script file. You have probably noticed that it results in couple of errors, as `ftp` fails on the first few lines of the batch file, which are not valid `ftp` commands (the `cd ...`, `call ...` and `ftp ...`).

Equivalently, the batch file would try to run all commands after `ftp ...` once `ftp` finishes, also failing, as those are not valid batch file commands. To avoid that, the hack uses `GOTO:EOF` to skip the rest of the batch file (EOF=eof of the file).

While you actually want to execute some commands after the `ftp`. At least the `cd` command. So do not skip the rest of the batch file. Skip only the `ftp` commands:

```
ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&goto AFTER_FTP
(ftp commands)
quit

:AFTER_FTP
cd %USERPROFILE%\Foilder\Subfolder
```

---

Note the `@` before `ftp`. That (and the `GOTO:EOF`) are clear signs, that the script you based your batch file on, was designed to start with `ftp` on the very first line and contain nothing else, but the `ftp` commands. You have deviated from that.

---

Alternatively, use some more capable FTP client that allows specifying the commands on its command-line without hacks.

For example with *my* [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), you can do:

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\Foilder\project\angular
call ng build

winscp.com /ini=nul /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@connection/" ^
    "cd httpdocs/project" ^
    "rm *.woff" ^
    "exit"

cd %USERPROFILE%\Foilder\Subfolder
```

There's a [guide for converting Windows `ftp` script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

Comment: Thank you so much! It was my fist time working with a .bat and didn't know how to make it work.